# UI is not updating while sending data from another view controller on UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, updating

i am using UITabBar to display two viewControllers, firstViewController is a uiview and secondViewController is a table view. what my need is when i clicked the second view table cell, the value should be updated on UILabel of firstViewController. 
my code is here,
In `secondviewcontroller.h`

```
 @interface firstviewcontroller {
 NSMutableArray *stationnamestobepassed;
  }
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stationnamestobepassed;
 @end
```

In `secondviewcontroller.m` declare this

```
@implementation firstviewcontroller
@synthesize stationnamestobepassed;

 -(void) someaction{
  stationnamestobepassed = [NSMutableArray     
    arrayWithObjects:@"string1",@"string2",@"string3"];
  secondviewcontroller = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"NIbName" 
Bundle:nil];
  secondviewcontroller.stationnamespassed = self.stationnamestobepassed;
  //i am not pushing the view controller.

 }

@end
```

In `firstviewcontroller.h` declare this

```
@interface secondviewcontroller {
 NSMutableArray *stationnamespassed;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stationnamespassed;


@end
```

In `firstviewcontroller.m` declare this

```
@implementation secondviewcontroller
@synthesize stationnamespassed;

  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
  //stationNameDisplay is a uilabel

stationNameDisplay.text=[stationnamespassed objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"station name %@",[stationnamespassed objectAtIndex:0]);

 }
  -(void) dealloc{
  [stationnamespassed release];
   [super release];
 }
@end
```

problem is , value is not updating and it gives NULL. but i tried with pushing the first vie and it works. actually i don't want to push that view controller because i was already exist on tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view will appear called out when you select the tab. while this line makes a new object of that controller, not that of tab controller.

```
secondviewcontroller = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"NIbName" 
Bundle:nil];
```

to do what you want. you will have to do some thing like this

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:/*your tab index on which desiredControllerResides*/];
NSArray* viewControllers= [navController viewControllers];
for(UIViewController *theController in viewControllers)
{
if([theController isKindOfClass:[secondviewcontroller]])
{
   theController.stationnamespassed = self.stationnamestobepassed;
//i.e  this line of your code secondviewcontroller.stationnamespassed = self.stationnamestobepassed;
}
}
```

Comment: i got the value updated while i put this line on secondViewController.m after initiating [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstview animated:YES];,  but i really don't want to push the view controller, i just want to update it. and viewDidLoad only calls once i think. my view controllers are in tabbarcontroller?

Comment: is your view appearing?  i think your view is not appearing on screen? em i right?

Comment: yes, sure its appearing. but only when i selected the tab for firstViewController its not updated by the value from secondViewController.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, sorry am confused, actually where do i put this code? secondviewcontroller.m?

Comment: just where you are setting the value. i've mention your code line. replace secondviewcontroller = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"NIbName" 
Bundle:nil];
  secondviewcontroller.stationnamespassed = self.stationnamestobepassed; with my given code

Comment: can you please specify this object theViewController

Comment: look. you want to set property of secondViewController which is in tabbar, but u'r making your own object with no effect ont he viewController in tabbar, so will have to first get the navigation controller on the index of tab bar where secondviewcontroller resides, then in that navigation controller, search all the viewcontrollers and check which one is the secondviewcontroller by matching class. theViewController is the required viewcontroller of whcih you want to set property

Comment: okay, i got some errors while adding those codes, am sure u have the right answer, sorry am just a beginner and confused sometimes about the objects, if([theViewController isKindOfClass:[secondviewcontroller]]) which objects is this? i have set the property for secondViewController

Comment: unknown receiver "theviewController" did you mean "UIViewController" and Unknown type name "theviewController"

Comment: sorry this was theController, really sorry i didn't saw that. see edited anser

Comment: okay let me explain what i understand from your code , secondviewcontroller is the object on secondViewController , right? and still have the errors, so what is this object theController?

Comment: i can't call theController.stationnamespassed